# tailwind class does not work, after moved files in /pages directory next.js

Tags: tailwind-css, next.js13, tailwind-in-js

when call components in 'app/page.tsx' it  work
[image]

Comment: add: import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
in my logIn file and its working but i think it is not a good version